# Change precedence of multiple click event over the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, operator-precedence

I've a web page which code can't be modified, I just can add some javascript/jquery in certain places.

Well, there is already an image with a click event associated to it. As I know the element CLASS, I added my own click event listener:

```
$(".co-page-link").click(function(e) {
    ....
}
```

The problem is that my click event fires before the one that was previously defined and I want to change this behavior. How can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you need to place your code below the previously added code as there is no API to order the event handers and there is no order of execution provided

Comment: ***practically*** If this take few second for example 3 second then run your code after 3 second. You can do this by setTimeout on Click of button.

Comment: If previous handler use some async function, you need to use some kind of callback regarding these async operations. I forgot, delegated events are fired after too.

Comment: I applied the solution pointed by F1beta. I know it's not the most elegant solution but it works. I check every 250ms if a certain field value has changed, once changed I stop the check (clearInterval)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no other click handler, you could just reverse order of bound handler:

```
[].reverse.call($._data($('.co-page-link')[0]).events.click);
```

If there is more than one element with class '.co-page-link', consider to use a loop.

Please note that this method is not publicly supported, syntax can vary from version to version. In older jquery version, use `$.data()` .

For more handler, if you wish last hanlder to become the first to be fired, you can unshift hanlder like that:

```
//set this handler in first with keeping other already bound events
var myH = $._data( $(".co-page-link")[0], "events" ).click.pop();
$._data( $(".co-page-link")[0], "events" ).click.unshift(myH);
```

Comment: is their any way to get the event information. I means I want to check that how much click event is attached to the button. Any guess

Comment: click handlers: $._data( $(".co-page-link")[0], "events" ).click  All handlers: $._data( $(".co-page-link")[0], "events" )  The first param is a node element, not a jquery object, that's why i use [0] {== get(0)}   But this will return only events bound using any jquery methods.

Comment: I didn't try this solution due to the comment you said about it's not publicly supported and syntax may vary. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> *"The problem is that my click event fires before the one that was previously defined and I want to change this behavior."*

Event handlers bound with jQuery are always called in the order they were bound, but if there are other handlers bound without using jQuery their order could vary depending on how they were bound (and may vary from browser to browser).

But handlers bound directly are called before delegated handlers bound to parent elements or the document, so if you bind a delegated handler at the document level then any handlers bound directly to the image will be executed before the event bubbles up, so then your handler would fire afterwards:

```
$(document).on("click", ".co-page-link", function(e) {
    // your code
});
```

The downside to this is that it won't work if other code prevents the bubbling, but it's something you could try.

Comment: It hasn't worked, so I guess somewhere there is the stop bubling